# ImageView still visible after remove

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to program a network card game with javafx but I have a problem.
I have programmed an own class CardImageView that extends from ImageView so that I can save the Card-Object there.
I'm able to add this CardImageView to my main group on my pc and on my "enemy's" pc and I am able to remove it on my pc.
But when I try to remove it at my "enemy's" pc it is still visible (but not "interactable".
For network connectivity I am using a Task that gives me the commands as Strings over the message property.

```
private void onCardRemoved(String msg) {
        System.out.println("CARD REMOVED BY: "+Thread.currentThread());
        String[] params = msg.split(";");
        //Calculating the coordinates of the card on screen
        double x = getWidth() - (Double.parseDouble(params[1])/100*getWidth()+card_width/2);
        double y = getHeight() - (Double.parseDouble(params[2])/100*getHeight()+card_height/2);
        CardImageView toRemove = null;
        System.out.println("To-Remove ("+x+"/"+y+")");
        //searching for the card in my group
        for(Node n :  spielfeld.getChildren()) {
            if(n instanceof CardImageView && n.getLayoutX() == x && n.getLayoutY() == y) {
                toRemove = (CardImageView) n;
                break;
            } 
        }
        //removing the card
        if(toRemove != null) spielfeld.getChildren().remove(toRemove);
    }
```

Comment: So do you think that remove( node) doesn' work or is something else wrong? Your whole removal code pretty much depends on some location numbers. Don't do that. Instead tell it which card to remove.

Comment: Why bother printing the current thread?  This method could only ever be run on the JavaFX application thread, so either wrap the call to it or the insides of it in Platform.runLater(), so it does not try to update the scene graph off the JavaFX application thread.

Comment: Comparing doubles with equals is [fraught with error](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/).

Comment: I don't know whats the problem
(to Roland:)
The Node gets removed from the group, i have tried. I can't do anything with it on the GUI anymore, but it is still shown.
I have tried to send the CardImageView but that doesn't work ... it was always null. And the calculations have the advantage that the screen width is unimportant. (The coordinates work, it is always found)

(to jewelsea:)
That was a test, it is the ApplicationThread.

Comment: @Burner: Don't send the CardImageView. Send a common identifier.

Comment: The "primary key" (that i compare in equals) is the card name but there can be more cards with the same name

Comment: There is nothing that would identify a specific card except it's position

Comment: But to remember:
my problem is not that the cardimageview isn't found or removed from y group, that happens and works fine
My problem is that it is still shown on the screen after beeing removed

Comment: I've added some new test-outputs.
Before I really compare the coordinates I output the comparison and the points, then when the comparison has worked I write the card and after I removed it I output that I removed. And I have got the following result
`To-Remove (793.0/229.0) //The coordinates for that I am searching
Found (793.0/229.0) //A Card that I found in my group
Compared: true //The comparison-result of coordinates
CARD FOUND: Act of Treason //The Card that I found
CARD REMOVED: Act of Treason`//The Card I removed`

Comment: Can't anybody help me with this?

Comment: I've changed it to an identifying number. But I have the same trouble as I had before.
The card is still shown (even though it does not react to any click-Events anymore)

Does anyone know what could be the reason?